# How do I unlock Expert Mode on mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Is there the Lunatic Cultist on Terraria 1.2.11979? I defeated the Golem but the Cultist won't spawn.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself?

Comment: Could you use Google? http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lunar_Events

Answer (score 3):

### Expert Mode is currently only available on PC

Expert Mode was introduced in patch 1.3.0.1. Currently, all versions other than PC are still in one of the 1.2 equivalent patches, and thus Expert Mode is not available. A list of the current version for each platform can be found on the main page of [The Official Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraria_Wiki).

The [Lunar Events](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lunar_Events) are similarly only available on PC at this time, as they were also introduced in patch 1.3.0.1. However, they are not related to Expert Mode, despite being made available in the same patch.

Comment: It's now on mobile, because of the 1.3.0.7 update